# Unable to call method from extended class

Tags: python-3.10

I have a Parent class that I extended into a child class, and the goal is to reuse an already created working functionality, but it seems an error occurred when using the parent class method

```
from sr import BaseClient
class Client(BaseClient):
    def __init__(self, credentials=None):
        ....
    def _request(self,path: str, params):
         pass


class Address(Client):
   def get_address(self, **kwargs):
       return self._request('path', kwargs)
```

Running test

```
import pytest
from .... import Addresses

def test_get_address():
    res = Addresses.get_address({'query': 'some',.....other here})
```

The error is pointing to the parent method called from the child class(Addresses)

> FAILED tests/test_api.py::test_get_addresses - AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_request'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're trying to call `get_address` as a static method, and the `dict` you're giving to the function (`{'query': 'some',.....other here}`) is passed as the `self` argument. This is why you get an error that a `dict` has no attribute `_request`, because it doesn't.

Perhaps you meant to instantiate the class first, like `Address().get_address()`?